# Salesforce Service Cloud - Table Account NULL values

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, salesforce, ssms, salesforce-service-cloud

I'm trying to obtain data from Service Cloud Salesforce but when I select the table in SSMS, the data is all NULL, so probably I'm not specifying the right columns or table.

[Salesforce Report Builder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uOpMt.png)

[Salesforce Source Editor (Visual Studio)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6UT9T.png)

When I run the report in Salesforce I can see that the country and postal code data are filled in, but when I read the documentation, I don't find the main column "Country" neither "Mailing Zip/Postal Code".
For the Zip Code, in this example, since it's also filled in the data about Billing Postal Code, this one I could obtain in the extraction, but for the country I can't find a column named "country", only "BillingCountry" and "ShippingCountry", but these columns do not contain any information.

Documentation:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.234.0.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_account.htm

Can anyone help here? I need to add on the select in salesforce source editor (visual studio) the right column names to obtain the country and the zip code.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

Your report mixes fields from Account and Contact joined together by Contact.AccountId = Account.Id. You could edit it and expand the left sidebar to see which field comes from which object.

Account has Billing and Shipping address (2 [sets of fields](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/compound_fields_address.htm) with actual names becoming BillingCity, BillingStreet... And Contact has Mailing address and Other Address.

So that's 4 * 6 fields across 2 tables out of the box. Can be muddied up further if you have "Person Accounts" enabled (some contacts get paired up as 1:1 relation to account instead of 1:n, in something that behaves a bit like materialised view for MS SQL people?). Also admin could rename one of the fields (API Names of columns stay the same but you'd see different labels in report and UI), add custom address fields...

See how these queries work for you. Try them out in Salesforce Developer Console (in web UI), or VSCode first, not in that tool you have.

Pure contacts

```soql
SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName, MailingStreet, MailingCity, MailingPostalCode
FROM Contact
WHERE MailingPostalCode = '4465-613'
LIMIT 10
```

Pure accounts

```soql
SELECT Id, Name, BillingStreet, BillingCity, BillingPostalCode
FROM Contact
WHERE BillingPostalCode = '4465-613'
LIMIT 10
```

Now JOIN (for normal Salesforce, B2B, where Account is more like a company and Contact is more like employee)

```soql
SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName, MailingStreet, MailingCity, MailingPostalCode, Account.Name, Account.City
FROM Contact
WHERE MailingPostalCode = '4465-613' AND Account.BillingPostalCode = '4465-613'
LIMIT 10
```

And since your second screenshot looks like you do have person accounts (more like B2C model, with standalone "1 man companies" like freelancers, doctors working in multiple hospitals, students in education...) try this one too

```soql
SELECT Id, Name, BillingCity, BillingPostalCode, ShippingCity, ShippingPostalCode, PersonMailingCity, PersonMailingPostalCode, PersonOtherCity, PersonOtherPostalCode
FROM Account
WHERE IsPersonAccount = true
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I think I don't have access to the Salesforce Developer Console, since I'm performing these tasks using the company account.

How can I join the two tables? 
I am using some columns from account and I want also to add the country, for instance, from the table contact. How can I do that? When I search the documentation, it only accepts MailingCountry, etc, but when I create the report in Salesforce there is a column named only "country".

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: You have access to UI because you can run reports, right? Click the gear/cog icon in upper right, does Developer Console option pop up? If you see just "Country" it's probably Contact.OtherCountry

Comment: I am able to run reports, but when I click the gear it only shows, "setup - for current app" and "service setup" options.
Currently I have this SELECT ... FROM Account, How do I join with the table Contact to obtain the Contact.OtherCountry, for instance?

Thank you,

PS: Sent you a message and friend request on Linkedin :)